# Opening in app, getting UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey from launchOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm trying to open a .pdf-file in my app. I adapted the Info.plist so a .pdf can be opened in my application.

I use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    thePDFurl = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    return YES;
}
```

In an other class, where my appDelegate (containing that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`), I've got the line:

```
appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDel.thePDFurl]];
```

Somehow, `theLabel` always shows (null). What am I missing?

Comment: *thePDFurl* shows the correct value if you print it in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* method?

Comment: I don't know, I can't NSLog it because the attachment of the mail has to be opened in this app. This means I can't run it through XCode. I did do `test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thePDFurl];` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and tried `[theLabel setText:appDel.test]`, resulting in an empty (not `(null)`, just nothing) label..?

Comment: Not related, but use `NSDictionary`'s `objectForKey:` instead of `NSKeyValueCoding`'s `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you were all right. It just so happened the view got loaded before the method applicationDidFinishLaunching was finished. Thanks all...

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers rather than posting a quasi-answer saying the answers provided were correct in the future.

Comment: Actually, the answer I found myself could be useful to others. In this case, it reminds users that the view was loaded before the method applicationDidFinishLaunching was finished. If people have a similar problem, this may help. Even though, every suggestive feedback entered in this page as answer, was upvoted. They still end up higher then my own answer...

Answer (score 8):

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. If so, ignore.

If you want the user to be able to "Open with..." a PDF using your app, you can implement

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

E.g.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"Open URL:\t%@\n"
     "From source:\t%@\n"
     "With annotation:%@",
     url, sourceApplication, annotation);

    NSString *filepath = [url path];
    //...
    return YES;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this works for both launching the app and calling it (i.e. if it's already in the background).

Comment: Hi, I can use the "Open with..", with which I can open the PDF with my app. The problem that occurs, is that the filepath from didFinishLaunching seems null to me. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does get called, although its options are (null)...

Answer (score 2):

You may retain the pdfurl variable and also get the absolute string value from NSURL using the [absoluteString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method.

```
[theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [appDel.thePDFurl absoluteString]]]
```

Comment: using `absoluteString` didn't work, I'm afraid. I also changed the initiation to `thePDFurl = [(NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] retain];`, without effect. Any ideas?

Comment: You got to use the getter. Try self.pdfurl = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]retain] ;

Comment: Or use retain when declaring property for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ,

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

`[viewController view]` was implicitly called and there was no `appDel.thePDFurl` assigned yet.